# Creating Random Number Generator with range

Tags: randomized-algorithms, random-number-generator

I've been trying to create my own random number library(in java). I've searched for randomization and [Blum Blum Shub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub) algorithm looks good. It needs a start value, it is not actually random. So i get [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) mod(10) for first value. Now i can generate random numbers. **My question is; how can i modify my structure with range**? I mean, i want to generate that numbers in a range. (I don't want to use java's another classes or functions) Any advices? Thanks in advance.

EDİT:I coded $\ x(n+1)= x(n)^2mod(M) \\$ formula and gived x(0) unix timestamp's last digit and M=191. So i get random numbers with Blum Blum Shub. But i want to get that numbers in a range. It is not about my code. It is about the formula and method actually.

Comment: start value + (random number%(end value - start value))
This May work for your case

Comment: If start=0 end=25 and unix digit=3, result will be 3.  If unix=5 result=0...
It mostly will return small digits. I need something like Blum Blum Shub and i'm looking a way for make it with range.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2509679/781723, http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html

Comment: Raw links don't help nearly so much as a simple explanation of why to visit the link.

Comment: Hi everyone. I changed my structure and i didn't use blum blum shub. I just use timestamp MOD(range) for range. My question was not so clear i think and i'm sorry for that and i'll work on subject again. But thank you all for time and help.